# Show where people transform into robot like creatures

Tags: story-identification, tv

I need help recognizing a show where people can transform using a phone-like thing into a robot or mythical-like creatures. Unfortunately I don't remember much details here are some things that I remember:

- The hero has a team: 1 girl and 1 boy (three people in total)
- They have an old master and live in a Monastery like place
- The girl is dark skinned and daughter of the main villain
- The hero turns into a red creature
- There are other masters as well and they all form a council of sorts
- The main villain was a master but was banished for evil
- This council holds a fighting tournament where the hero wins and gets a new creature which is the same as his old red one but gold in colour
- The villain makes three identical boys who look the same and compete with the hero's team: they transform into a combined 3 headed dragon
- Also for some reason I remember the word ZODIAC to be somehow associated with the show

Comment: Is this a cartoon? Live action? If animated, was it realistic? Cartoony? Exaggerated?

Comment: Using a phone-like thing to turn into various powerful beings sounds a lot like the comic book *Dial H for Hero*, but as far as I can tell, it was never turned into a tv show. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dial_H_for_Hero